# Problem while sign > serialize > deserialize > verify using web crypto

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

As a part of my JS code, using web crypto, I wanted to sign a string, serialize it and later deserialize it and verify it.
For this I created these custom functions `createHexTokenFromStrClaim` and `verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim`. However my code is not behaving as expected.

Minimal working code:

```js
const keyUsages = ["sign","verify"];
const algo = {
    name: "HMAC",
    hash: {name: "SHA-512"}
};

class Util{
    static text_encoder=new TextEncoder();
    static text_decoder=new TextDecoder();
    static characters  = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    static hexEncode(str) {
        let hex = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
            if (charCode < 128) {
            hex += charCode.toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            } else if (charCode < 2048) {
            hex += ((charCode >> 6) | 0xC0).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            hex += ((charCode & 0x3F) | 0x80).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            } else {
            hex += ((charCode >> 12) | 0xE0).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            hex += (((charCode >> 6) & 0x3F) | 0x80).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            hex += ((charCode & 0x3F) | 0x80).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
            }
        }
        return hex;
    }

    static hexDecode(hex) {
        let str = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
            const byte = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
            str += String.fromCharCode(byte);
        }
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(str)); // Handle UTF-8 encoding
    }
    
    static async createHexTokenFromStrClaim(algo,str_claim,crypto_key){
        const hex_str_claim= Util.hexEncode(str_claim);
        const uint = Util.text_encoder.encode(hex_str_claim);
        const ab = uint.buffer;

        const sign = await crypto.subtle.sign(algo,crypto_key,ab);
        const des = Util.text_decoder.decode(sign);
        console.log(new Uint8Array(sign));
        
        const hex_sign=Util.hexEncode(des);

        return hex_str_claim+"."+hex_sign;
      }
    
    static async verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim(algo,hex_token,crypto_key){
        let hex_str_claim,hex_sign;
        [hex_str_claim,hex_sign]=hex_token.split(".");
        
        if(hex_str_claim && hex_sign){
            const uint = Util.text_encoder.encode(hex_str_claim);
            const ab = uint.buffer;

            const des = Util.hexDecode(hex_sign);
            const sign = Util.text_encoder.encode(des);
            console.log(sign);

            const r = await crypto.subtle.verify(algo,crypto_key,sign.buffer,ab);
            if(r){
                return Util.hexDecode(hex_str_claim);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}

(async()=>{
    const crypto_key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(algo,true,keyUsages);
    const message = "Hello world こんにちは、元気ですか ईश्वरेण सह एकतां प्राप्तुं एषः महान् दिवसः अस्ति";
    const token  = await Util.createHexTokenFromStrClaim(algo,message,crypto_key);
    console.log(token);

    const claim = await Util.verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim(algo,token,crypto_key);
    console.log(claim);
})();
```

Hex Encoder is used as encoding like base64 introduces special characters , which causes issues with other part of the code.

Problem:
Verification seems to be failing. Specifically in `verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim` the sign is coming completely different after encoding it using `const sign = Util.text_encoder.encode(des);`

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Have checked most of the resources about encoding and decoding.
Have checked most of the resource for signing and verifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hexEncode()` method hex encodes a string using the UTF-8 encoding. You apply this to the message, but also to the UTF-8 decoded signature/HMAC.
While the former is of course not a problem, the latter is wrong and the cause of the problem, because the UTF-8 decoding/encoding of an HMAC *irreversibly corrupts* it (keep in mind that an HMAC, just like a hash, a ciphertext etc. is not UTF-8 compliant).
You can immediately recognize the corruption by outputting `hex_sign`, which contains multiple *0xefbfbd* sequences. This is the UTF-8 encoding of the replacement character used for non-UTF8-compatible byte sequences during the UTF-8 decoding.
The fix is to *directly* hex encode the *raw* HMAC without taking the (wrong) detour via the UTF-8 decoding/encoding.

You also sign the hex encoded message. This is not wrong, but actually unnecessary, it is more efficient to sign the *raw* message.

If your code is modified accordingly, verification works:

```js
const keyUsages = ["sign","verify"];
const algo = {
    name: "HMAC",
    hash: {name: "SHA-512"}
};

class Util{
    static text_encoder = new TextEncoder();
    static text_decoder = new TextDecoder();
    
    static ab2hex(ab) { 
        return Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(ab), x => ('00' + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    }

    static hex2ab(hex) {
        return new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {return parseInt(h, 16)}));
    }
    
    static async createHexTokenFromStrClaim(algo, str_claim, crypto_key) {  
        const claim = Util.text_encoder.encode(str_claim);
        const sign = await crypto.subtle.sign(algo, crypto_key, claim); // more efficient: sign the raw message
        const sign_hex = Util.ab2hex(sign); // Fix: hex encode the signature directly
        const claim_hex = Util.ab2hex(claim) 
        return claim_hex + "." + sign_hex;
    }
    
    static async verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim(algo, hex_token, crypto_key) {
        let claim_hex, hex_sign;
        [claim_hex, hex_sign] = hex_token.split(".");        
        if(claim_hex && hex_sign) {
            const claim = Util.hex2ab(claim_hex);
            const sign = Util.hex2ab(hex_sign); // hex decode the signature
            const r = await crypto.subtle.verify(algo, crypto_key, sign, claim); // verify the raw message
            if(r) {
                return Util.text_decoder.decode(claim);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}

(async() => {
    const crypto_key = await crypto.subtle.generateKey(algo, true, keyUsages);
    const message = "Hello world こんにちは、元気ですか ईश्वरेण सह एकतां प्राप्तुं एषः महान् दिवसः अस्ति";
    const token = await Util.createHexTokenFromStrClaim(algo, message, crypto_key);
    const claim = await Util.verifyHexTokenAndGetStrClaim(algo, token, crypto_key);
    console.log("token:", token);
    console.log("claim:", claim);
})();
```